# Sending Firebase Notifications Within A Specified Time Period

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

When I send a Firebase push notification, my server slows down because all users open the application at the same time.
Is it possible to send notifications in groups rather than at once?
For example, dividing all users into 10 groups and sending notifications to each group with a 5-minute interval.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase allows [topic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging) and [device group](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group) messaging. It should help you. For IOS you can use [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/device-group)